# Неправильно отображается текст

Tags: дефект, конкурс

[image: Так выглядит дефект]

Чтобы воспроизвести дефект:

1. Надо задать вопрос.
2. За несколько минут до срока, когда можно будет назначить премию, зайти на страницу с вопросом и подождать (не перегружать страницу!)
3. Ко времени, когда за вопрос уже можно назначить премию, начнет отображаться неправильная надпись (см. снимок).